# Define an array of LinkedList in java used of @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

i know this have been previously answered and i have read  the answers in [How to properly define an array of linked list in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654229/how-to-properly-define-an-array-of-linked-list-in-java)   and  [How do I fix "The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion...'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367626/how-do-i-fix-the-expression-of-type-list-needs-unchecked-conversion)

And i use this, as is recommended in the second answer of the second link

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void myMethod()
{
    //...
}
```

Because in my code (example below) i need to use a static LinkedList[] so after reading the data i will have the size of the number i'll use in "Q = new LinkedList[size of data];". And i need the static LinkedList[] because i use it in many function

```
 static LinkedList<Integer>[] Q;

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 static public void function(){
 int r=3;
 Q = new LinkedList[10];//this gives the warnning without "the unchecked"
 Q[r]=new LinkedList<Integer>();
 }
 static public void function2(){
   //using  Q[r] for different r
 }
```

It's still giving me the warning when i compile

```
    memoria/bosques.java:3150: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: LinkedList
                Q = new LinkedList[10];
                        ^
    missing type arguments for generic class LinkedList<E>
    where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class LinkedList
```

Compiling this in windows's eclipse works well, but in linux doesn't

Is there something i can do?

Comment: Why not switch to something like ``List<List<E>>``?

Comment: Just because you've turned off warnings for unchecked conversions doesn't mean you should use raw types.  Use `Q = new LinkedList<Integer>[10]`.

Comment: @Jishnu Prathap  i declare it with static LinkedList<Integer>[] Q;

Comment: @ John Bollinger  Q = new LinkedList<Integer>[10] it's not allowed (and therefore is an error)

Answer (score 0):

Finally instead of using @SuppressWarnings("unchecked"), i used ArrayList < LinkedList< Integer>> so instead of defining a Q = new LinkedList[4], i do a for to  add the new LinkedList:

```
        static ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> Q2 = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();

        public static void function(){
        for(int i=0;i<4; i++){
                            LinkedList<Integer> fila=new LinkedList<Integer>();
                            Q2.add(fila);
        }
                        Q2.get(0).add(3);
                        Q2.get(0).add(4);
                        Q2.get(0).add(5);
                        Q2.get(2).add(13);
                        Q2.get(2).add(14);
                        Q2.get(2).add(15);

                        for(LinkedList<Integer> fila:Q2){
                            System.out.print("Miembros");

                            for(Integer it:fila){
                                System.out.print("->{");
                                System.out.print(it);
                                System.out.print("}");
                            }
                            System.out.println("");
                        }

        }
```

Comment: @Jishnu Prathap , what do you mean? i changed all my structures of Q[r]  with a Q.get(r) and works the same and it errase the warning  unchecked...ArrayList was a relevant factor to solve my problem and i put a little example of how it works or you say this because i asked about @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")?

Comment: You were getting compile error while creating linkedlist arrays and you solved it by creating arraylist of linkedlist right? Actually I think this is a different implementation of your program without compile warnings but not answer to your question.